# how to build Life Time Value model

Tags: machine-learning

Does anyone have any ideas about what would be a good way to go about building a user Life Time Value model? I have a website with two kinds of revenue, pay per click and impression from advertisments. My initial instincts are telling me I will need to use a unsupervised clustering algorithm to segment individual users by some kind of rough LTV metric. and then maybe re define a revenue distribution for each cluster. Anyway, any helpful ideas would be appreciated.